# c# System.IO.File - The process cannot access the file

Tags: c#, system.io.file

So this is my current code where im using the file to Write, Create and then write again but its saying it being used by another process.

```
    private void btn_Finish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if((txt_setText.Text != "" || txt_setText.Text != "Enter your text here...") && txt_copyItem.Text != "")
            {
                lbl_error.Visible = false;
                //gets the amount of enties made and sets the int
                amount = Convert.ToInt32(File.ReadAllText(@"Files/data.txt"));
                amount += 1;
                File.WriteAllText(@"Files/data.txt", amount.ToString());

                //execute addCopy function
                addCopy(txt_copyItem.Text, txt_setText.Text);
                MainTab.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
            else
            {
                lbl_error.Visible = true;
            }

    }

    private void addCopy(string name, string clip)
    {
        string path = @"Files/User/c" + amount.ToString() + ".txt";
        File.Create(path);
        File.WriteAllText(path, (name + "," + clip));
    }
```

And when I operate the code i get this error:

The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\jakey\onedrive\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\copyboard\copyboard\bin\Debug\Files\User\c1.txt' because it is being used by another process.

How do i fix?
Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Remove the `File.Create(path);` line.

Comment: `File.WriteAllText` method would create file if it's not exist, so File.Create line is useless here

Comment: `File.Create()` opens the file and returns a `Stream` which you can use to write data to the file. The file will remain "opened" as long as this stream is open, and since `File.WriteAllText()` also attempts to open the file, you get the error message. As @DavidArno you can delete the `File.Create()`, I just thought you might want to know why you get the error message.

Answer (score -2):

Solved:

```
    private void addCopy(string name, string clip)
    {
        string path = @"Files/User/c" + amount.ToString() + ".txt";
        StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(path);
        w.WriteLine((name + "," + clip));
        w.Close();
    }
```

Just replaced File.Create(path) with StreamWriter

Comment: This is a terrible solution, FYI. You should keep using the File API.